# Avatar of Fire and Elemental Equlibrium

Tags: path-of-exile

I saw a [character](http://www.pathofexile.com/fullscreen-passive-skill-tree/AAAAAwEBA-4EswthDR8NfA3ND6sUIBZvFr8XLxhqGYoaOBqPHM4dFB2qHb4kiySqJpUnLyj6K1AvbzOHNZI2PTbpOuE8KDwtPfxBh0ZxTeNObVBHVUtV1lfJWAdYY1nzW_RfP1-wYeJirGTnZlRmnmebaPJsjG1sb55wu3IPcql4L3zZfOV_xoCkgseDCYNfg8yExYzPj0aQVZMnlG-YrZuhm7WcMpy-naqhL6IApcSmV6yqrj6vbK-Nr6e0DLc-vorBxcM6xPbGrsbYykrK09i92RPhiONq5FHquuwY7w7wH_Gz8kX2SPba9zL56PrS-wn-Cv5J_lT-jw==) with this two keystones picked... But all they will give together is +25% to monsters' resistance except of the first hit, because we can't lower fire-res as of we can't deal non-fire damage. So, what is the profit?

Comment: Did you accidentally hit submit halfway through your post?

Comment: Sorry, it was full... but something eat half of it)

Comment: What's the "Character's" means of damage? What gems/tools/uniques does he use?

Comment: I don't know, because the character is empty now as you see. But Is there any way to go arount the AoF?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I had to guess, based on the fact that they took Conduit and various passives that improve curses and auras, I'd say maybe they were doing something of a support character for party play.  They'd be giving good curses and auras, sharing charges, and giving all enemies -50% to ice and lightning resists.